# Save Multiple Progressive Web Apps to Home screen from one website

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a website where I would like to be able to have different subfolders act as separate PWA's and be saved to the home screen separately. E.g.

### PWA #1 - specifically branded for client #1

~/ClientOne/ClientOnePWA.html

~/ClientOne/serviceworker.js

~/ClientOne/manifest.json

### PWA #2 - specifically branded for Other Client

~/OtherClient/OtherClientPWA.html

~/OtherClient/serviceworker.js

~/OtherClient/manifest.json

My question is this: is there any way to have these two exist side-by-side on the same android home screen?

I had thought that since the service workers and manifests were in a separate scope it would treat these as separate web applications, but right now it's treating them as one big application (which I'd really like them to be separate for our business use case).

Currently I can add the PWA for client One to the home screen of an Android device, but then when I go to 'OtherClientPWA.html' I can't add it to the home screen. Instead, it gives me the option to 'Open Client One PWA' where 'Add to home screen' should be on the chrome menu.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add two sub domain alisas for your app1 and app2 like below.

App1.mydomain.com
App2.mydomain.com

This can be routed to ur client1 and otherclient in ur server side. This will help in maintaining two apps in a cleaner way as well as service worker sees it as two different app. This will help keeping two different icons to launch as well.

Comment: Implemented this and the service workers are sand-boxed just as desired. Also as you said the architecture should now be a little cleaner, too. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps :)

Comment: How about the fact that a service worker must belong to the same origin as the requesting page and manifest start_url has to be relative to origin?

Comment: @jeboy yes.. start URL is relative. Shouldn't have the full domain. Just as index.html for. just example, unless you want to maintain two different base URL.

Comment: Is this by standard or current limitation of Chrome browser?

Comment: Its a standard and wont be a limitation that you can expect to be over. It will also help teams maintain multiple applications under same domain in different logical units .